# Android AdMob Loading Problem

Tags: android, admob

I have used adMob to display ads in my android app.

but it takes some time to load the ad. So I want to display static banner while the ad is loading. The probelm I am facing is that, the adListeners events are not responding which cause the ad to overlap over the static banner

how can I hide the banner when adMob actually loads ad and how do I know that ad is loaded and actually shown in the Application ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `ImageView` for default banner right under the ad view. So no need to hide/show the default banner. When the ad loads the default banner will go under it and will not be visible.